# extracting a substring to use in simple date format

Tags: java, hashmap, indexof

I am reading log files and need to extract the date and year from certain lines in order to then use simple date format and find out the average time in between 2 actions. An example of what a line that I would need the date from looks like this.

```
(INFO ) [07 Feb 2013 08:04:39,161] -- ua, navigation, fault
```

I can't figure out if I should split the the line twice or use the substring function. Also I don't think I need to include that last number when converting to simple date format (the 161).

Comment: 161 is milliseconds. If you already have it, maybe you can use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using regex groups to extract the String you want. You can use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("you regex pattern with () around the bit you wanna extract");
Matcher m = p.matcher(theLine);
if (m.find()) {
    String date =  m.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use regex to extract the required data from log files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for using substring:

```
final int from = line.indexOf('[') + 1;
final int to = line.indexOf(']', from); // or , if you do not want to have the last number included
final String timestampAsString = line.substring(from, to);
```

BTW: Add some from/to-checks if valid indices have been found - for example to detect errors early on when the log format changed.

Comment: you may get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `[` is not available.